# Convert character class to numeric without NA

Tags: r, character

I have a variable  with class "character", for example:

```
class(itc$`Mobile-cellular telephone subscriptions`)
[1] "character"

(itc$`Mobile-cellular telephone subscriptions`)
[1] "19'709'038"     "3'400'955"      "43'227'643"     "71'336"         "13'884'532"
```

When I use `as.numeric` all the values becomes NA.

Comment: either split them first or remove the delimiter completely...whichever you need

Comment: Here is an example using the `stringr` library: `as.numeric(str_replace_all("19'709'038", "'", ""))`

Comment: Or for the whole vector you could do: `cellphone <- c("19'709'038", "3'400'955", "43'227'643", "71'336")`
`sapply(cellphone, function(x) unname(as.numeric(str_replace_all(x, "'", ""))))`

Comment: The `destring()` function extracts only numeric values from a string. Might be useful. https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/taRifx/versions/1.0.6/topics/destring

Answer (score 0):

We can use `str_extract`

```
library(stringr)
sapply(str_extract_all(itc$`Mobile-cellular telephone subscriptions`, '[0-9.]+'), as.numeric)
```